# Replacing special characters by null

Tags: informatica

Is there any function to replace the special characters by null in informatica

if we used replacestr function, i think we should specify all special characters

as follows replacestr(input,'!','~','@','#','$','%','^','&','*',null)

But we dont know what are teh special characters will be coming as input.

can u please let me know that which function will be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try, REG_MATCH(input,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]') ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, I know you might not need it anymore .. I just seen this question. I suggest that you use a regular expression that looks for anything but chars/numbers/spaces/newlines and replace them with null. It will be a Replace transformation with the patternSearch "your regular Expression" and null for the field ReplaceWith .

I am assuming by all special characters are all characters besides what I mentioned in the Regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
REG_REPLACE('[^[:print:]]',NULL)
```

This will find all non-print characters and replace them with null (I think it'd be better to replace with '', but thats just my opinion. Informatica uses POSIX-standard, so you can use others like alnum, punct, whatever you need.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions